# Set gitlab external web port number

Tags: gitlab

How do I change gitlab's default port 80 to a custom port number?

There are two approaches I've tried:

**Set the port in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
external_port "8888"
```

Then run reconfigure:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

**Set port in /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml**

```
production: &base
  #
  # 1. GitLab app settings
  # ==========================

  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: gitlab.blitting.com
    port: 8888
    https: false
```

Then restart gitlab

```
gitlab-ctl stop
gitlab-ctl start
```

With both of these, gitlab continues to run on the default 80 port number.

Comment: Updating gitlab-http.conf nginx configuration worked, is that the correct process?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Chad Carbert answer still applies but just want to add extra for version 7.0.0.

Open "/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb" in your text editor where currently I have **external_url** `http://127.0.0.1/` or similar to that. I may need to change external_url with dns including port number (eg. 'http://gitlab.com.local:81/') then reconfigure using command "sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure"  Gitlab is now working on port 81.

**Step by step:**

1. `sudo -e /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
2. Change **external_url** from `yourdomain.com` to `yourdomain.com:9999`
    `9999` -> Port you want it to run
3. `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: For me gitlab is now accessible through both 8080 and 8081 (the port I added). Any idea how I can free up 8080?

Comment: Stopping and starting it again solved the issue.

Comment: If this doesn't work, check the logs using `gitlab-ctl tail` to find if the ports collide.

Comment: Is there an alternative command for `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` if I don't have `gitlab-ctl`? Just restarting should do, right?

Comment: I think no, yes restarting server should do.

Comment: I can't believe it is this simple. In my case, Apache was already the server on port 80 hence the need for a port.

Comment: See the "#unicorn['port'] = '8080'" value in the config file.

Comment: I have bitnami virtual machine, when I do the edit above it works. But after restarting virtual machine the file gitlab.rb would be changed to the previous value!!!

Comment: @kamil I am not much aware of bitnami but it works on docker (not sure) and probably overwriting gitlab.rb every time when configure. It must have other workarounds to set your own gitlab.rb

Comment: any suggestion on how to set external url and not loosing it on restart, note that there might be a script getting internal ip address and changing it in gitlab.rb

Comment: I'm using a dockerized gitlab (v11.1.4) and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 8):

Very simple way to change defaults port number

```
gitlab-ctl stop
```

Edit the file in centos or linux: `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf`
Change `listen *:80;` to what you want Ex:- `90`

Then

Don't run the command: `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
If `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` it configured gitlab by defaults and remove changes.

So only run: `gitlab-ctl start`

Comment: At least won't work for omnibus package

Answer (score 6):

I'm also having this same issue. I don't have my `gitlab.rb` in the same location as you, but do have it installed via dpkg at the `/opt` path you mentioned.

If you've installed it via the package, all self-contained in that `/opt` directory, then you might find changing the port at :

- `/opt/gitlab/embedded/conf/nginx.conf`
- `/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/templates/default/nginx-gitlab-http.conf.erb`

Issue #6581: [.deb package install on Ubuntu 12.04 - Port number in gitlab.yml file is ignored](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6581)

Comment: How did this help? I'm still not getting anywhere with this - gitlab is insisting on using port 80 - which it can't because apache is already using it. Any specifics about what you did? Changing ports in those files did nothing.

Answer (score 5):

With Ubuntu 17.04 and gitlab-ce 9.2.2, on local network

These steps worked for me:

1. Edit `gitlab.rb` file.

`sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

2. Add your optional listen port to end of file.

`nginx['listen_port'] = 8181`

3. Stop apache if needed, and reconfigure gitlab

`sudo service apache2 stop
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

4. Start apache if you stop that.

`sudo service apache2 start`

5. Finished, now gitlab is available on your ip address with selected port.

'http://localhost:8181'

Answer (score 4):

My main issue was that new users were not getting the custom port number in the emails that the system sent. Otherwise, manually writing the custom port in the address bar led users to the Gitlab install.

I did [this install](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/7-4-stable/doc/install/installation.md) on **Ubuntu 14.04** instead of the Omnibus. So somehow I don't have `gitlab-ctl`. (It exists in `/usr/bin`, but the target of the symlink wasn't installed somehow. I'll fix that separately if I really have to.)

Anyway, I used a variant of the second approach, writing the correct port into  `/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml`:

```
production: &base
  #
  # 1. GitLab app settings
  # ==========================

  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: my.gitlab.host.com
    port: 3722
```

Since I don't have `gitlab-ctl`, I used `service`:

```
sudo service gitlab restart
```

That worked for me. New users that I sent the email to received a link which contained the correct URL.

Answer (score 2):

In Amazon Linux using the Centos 6 package I had to configure the file:

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/gitlab/attributes/default.rb
```

and then do the

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

command to finally get the port change.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Gitlab 7.5.3 omnibus 5.2.1 ci on Debian Squeeze.
To change the default port for nginx add the _gitlab_port_ to */etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb*:

My **/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**:

```
external_url = 'gitlab.example.org'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_port'] = 12345
```

After changing the port, you have to call `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `gitlab-ctl restart` in your command line.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the **external_url** value on Gitlab configuration file.

Follow these steps:

1. Edit config file by run this command

> ```
> sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
> ```

2. Find the **external_url** and change to your URL and port

[image: Change external_url]

3. Exit and save the change (**ctrl + X**)
4. Run this command to reconfiguration the Gitlab local server

> ```
> sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
> ```

If you use the webserver like Nginx you must change the external port from the reverse proxy in the configuration of Nginx.