# Permanently change gitlab server port

Tags: gitlab

Trying to use a recent version of gitlab, I'm despairing somewhat with its configuration process (or rather that of its "embedded packages").

I have installed the gitlab-omnibus package (version 7.4.3) on my Ubuntu server 14.04, which is also running an apache for other stuff; therefore I want to change the port that gitlab is running under.

Supposedly it can all be done through editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb, by adding the port number at the end, like so:

```
external_url='http://myurl:myport'
```

and then running

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Well, that doesn't work. nginx still wants to connect to port 80, as a

```
gitlab-ctl tail nginx
```

spews out:

```
date&time [emerg] 31321#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

Searching the web, I have found numerous mentions of such problems, and numerous files which should be edited (see e.g. this other question: https://serverfault.com/a/587800/151655). The only thing I found so far that actually worked somewhat was changing the port in the file `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf`; but apparently this change only lasts until the next run to `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.
So is there some way to make this change stick, or do I need to avoid running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` or do the manual adaptation everytime again?

By the way I find it very irritating that even though the actual binding of the network port fails, `gitlab-ctl start` isn't reporting anything out of the ordinary at all (just as if everything worked normally). Am I missing something here or is this just very bad usability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple answer it seems - I initially had changed the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` because of some error in `gitlabctl reconfigure` ; however the current syntax wasn't right (but apparently ignored, and not causing errors); I was using `external_url='http://myurl:myport'`, but apparently

```
external_url "http://myurl:myport"
```

has to be used, then it works!